# how to configure tsconfig file in git submodule ? #forTsChecker

Tags: git, webpack, tsconfig

I have this Project and in this project , I have a git submodule as a sharing component , structure like this.

```
Porject
├─node_modules
├─src
│ ├─App
│ ├─common
│ │ ├─Components
├─CommonUI <== sub module
│ ├─.storybook
│ ├─node_modules
│ ├─src
│ │ ├─Components
│ ├─index.ts
│ └─tsconfig.json
├─tsconfig.json
├─webpack.config.js
└─typings
```

if I install dependencies in git shubmodule , the main project will got error.

> Type '{ onChange: (e: any) => void; type: string; checked: boolean; className: string; form?: string | undefined; slot?: string | undefined; style: CSSProperties |
> undefined; title?: string | undefined; ... 274 more ...; step?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes, HTMLInputElement>'.
> Type '{ onChange: (e: any) => void; type: string; checked: boolean; className: string; form?: string | undefined; slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; title?: string | undefined; ... 274 more ...; step?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'InputHTMLAttributes'.
> Types of property 'style' are incompatible.
> Type 'import("MainProject/CommonUI/node_modules/@types/react/index").CSSProperties | undefined' is not assignable to type 'React.CSSProperties | undefined'.

but if I remove node_modules in the git submodle , this error won't show up. I'll build my project just fine.

in the main project the tsconfig.json is like this

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS"
    }
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "noLib": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "preserve",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@Common/UI": ["gitSubmodule/src"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "include": ["src/**/*", "typings", "SunglinkUI"]
}
```

and here is the tsconfig file in git submodule.

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

the point is why? why remove node_modules in the git submodule will be ok but not ok when I install some dependencies